# URLCache and eviction control

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlcache

Just want to share my indignation. Maybe someone will advise something.
There is a class `URLCache`. As I understand it, this class does not provide any tools to perform actions when an object is about to be evicted or removed from the cache. No `delegate`, no `override`.

Thus, this class does not allow to control which objects are evicted from the cache. After all, the related class `NSCache` has `NSCacheDelegate`. Why `URLCache` doesn't have the same?

So, to control the operation of the cache, I will have to create my own cache class from scratch.
Another oddity is that I can’t find 3rd party cache frameworks that allow to control events of eviction. 
Doesn't anyone care?

Comment: Why don't you just use `NSCache` if that fits all your needs?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Because NSCache is a storage that lives during program run only. But I need cache to store data after program relaunch.

Comment: You could take advantage of either `CoreData` or `UserDefaults`. Both of which are fairly easy to interface with and may require objects to be encoded before storing them in the device's memory location.

Comment: @KSigWyatt When utilizing UserDefaults how to provide cache eviction? I think auto-eviction is most complicated part for any custom cache. All the rest can be done easily.